# How to get Windows 8 boot menu to choose OS in a dual boot of Windows 8 and Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot, grub

I recently dual booted my system - Windows 8 and Ubuntu, installing the latter first. Now, when I boot into my system, I get the Ubuntu grub menu instead of the Windows 8 boot menu that has only two options. Both the operating systems are in Legacy boot mode. Is there a way to get the Windows 8 boot menu instead of Ubuntu's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install a dual-boot of Ubuntu, one of the frustrating things that you’ll immediately notice is that Ubuntu is now set as the default operating system in the Grub loader. There’s an easy way to switch back to using Windows as the default.

To make this change, you’ll first have to boot into Ubuntu, and then run the following command:

```
sudo gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst
```

Find this section of the file:

```
## default num
# Set the default entry to the entry number NUM. Numbering starts from 0, and
# the entry number 0 is the default if the command is not used.
#
# You can specify ‘saved’ instead of a number. In this case, the default entry
# is the entry saved with the command ‘savedefault’.
# WARNING: If you are using dmraid do not change this entry to ‘saved’ or your
# array will desync and will not let you boot your system.
default 0
```

The important line is the last one. You will need to change that number 0 to match the Windows boot section. Typically it’s always going to be 4 on a default dual-boot configuration. Change this value to 4, and then save and reboot your machine. You should go into Windows instead of Ubuntu automatically.

Note: The blocks at the bottom of the file match the items in the menu. You can change this value to match whichever item you want as default, just remember that numbering starts at 0. (arr howtogeek.co.uk)

Comment: one of my friends faced the same problem and when I directed him to this answer he found that /boot/grub/menu.lst is completely empty. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Or boot to Windows 8 and use a BCD editor to overwrite grub. You can also use windows start-up DVD to rewrite the BCD. I'm doing about the same thing, but I'm trying to get the metro windows boot manager... still can't get it off of the legacy text-style loader.